How to know if a segmentation fault will happen?
I'm new in c programming and i am wondering if there is any sure way to know if a program will segfault.
I came to know about the "valgrind" function but some of my codes still encounter this problem since i can't possibly test all cases of some codes.I would greatly appreciate any advice.

Is there a way to guarantee that no seg faults will occur, you mean? Not using pointers at all is a good start, but that is often a tough call when the language is c.

"will this crash if I run it?" - run it and see. "is there an input that would make this crash?" - one tool for that are "fuzzers" which try various inputs to break a program. "my program crashed, how do I find the reason" - use valgrind, debugger to look at the details of the crash and look at the code to analyze possible reasons for it.

The answer to the question "Is there any sure way to know if a program will segfault?" is "No, there is no sure way". It is similar to the question "Is there any sure way to know if a program is bug free?", answer: "No, there is no sure way"

"is there a static analyzer that would reliably warn me of potential crashes without running the program?" - no (prohibited by theory). See also: halting problem.

@teapot418 While it may not be able to answer for sure, it's certainly possible to warn about possible/likely cases. For example, it's not hard to detect uses of uninitialized variables, my IDE warns about them.

Your best bet is to code defensively. "Hope for the best, prepare for the worst."

If you have a program that sometimes crashes under unknown conditions there is no magic solution. You have to collect as much information as you can and then solve the puzzle why that could have happened.

@teapot418 would you mind sharing the link to "fuzzers"?

@teapot418 whilst static analysis will not get all bad pointer errors it gets enough of the common ones that humans and especially beginners tend to make to be worth using. It cannot find every potential fault but the ones that use a full dataflow analysis can spot paths through code where some variable ends up not properly initialised before first use without having to run the code at all.

Well, I guess it depends on what exactly you are asking. Is there a way to know whether or not a specific program with a specific input in a specific environment will segfault? Yes. If there is a way for any program on any environment? No.

You may use sanitizers. Pass the flag -fsanitize=address to the compiler

Would you agree to rephrase your question? Basically the answer to the question as currently asked is "You can't.". Because even if there is an error in your program which is a violation of memory useage, you cannot know whether it will have a segementation fault - at least not an observable one. Do you mean an observable one? I.e. the well-hated crash with error message? Or do you mean a memory useage mistake that might or might not cause an observable one? That I consider a different question. A matter of question interpretation of course. Please phrase unambiguously to allow answering.

From the comments and which one of them you found interesting, you probably want to ask something like "Which test methods and tools exist for testing against memory useage design failures?" or "How can I prove that a program will never segfault?". Or "How to find mistake in memory useage?" I nitpick on the phrasing and precision, because I actually find the question interesting and want to help making it answerable, so that a good Q/A set can be born. ;-)

Read up on undefined behavior. Avoid it as much as you possibly can. Check return codes from functions. When you proceed from one function call to the next without verifying the condition of the program, you open up the possibility for behavior like segmentation faults.

@teapot418 It's not possible to have a program that will identify any program that will segfault, but it's absolutely possible to write a program that can, for many programs, catch the instances of undefined behavior that can lead to segfaults. (And valgrind is an excellent example of such.)

Alright thank you all for your answers.
